# How to install .deb when dpkg and apt are not available?

Tags: linux, apt, package-management

**Update:**
Besides `uname -a`, I also tried the following methods to get the distro info.

```
[root@HTNICE usr]# lsb_release -d
-sh: lsb_release: not found
[root@HTNICE usr]# cat /etc/*-release
cat: can't open '/etc/*-release': No such file or directory
```

**Original question:**
I'm working on an embedded board. According to the few-page-only manual, it comes with Ubuntu 12.04 yet I found the kernel not that old.
[image]

The problem is: I'm unable to install anything I want. When I tried `apt`, it said "command not found". Downloaded the .deb file and then using `dpkg`, it said there is no status file. The `/var/lib/` directory doesn't even exist.
[image]

Most of the system commands I find common in other Linux distributions point to `busybox`, including the `dpkg` I intended to use to install `apt`.
[image]

Is there any way to bring the `apt` back so I can start install the packages I need for my work? Thanks.

Comment: Don't post images, and try creating the directory `/var/lib/dpkg` and retry.

Comment: The error message shows that your `busybox` has indeed (rudimentary) `dpkg` function included. The problem seems to be that the package system is not initialized which will probably lead to a mess of unresolved dependencies.

Comment: You need neither apt, nor dpkg to install packages - deb packages can be simply unpacked and installed directly. Considering you have no DPKG database using APT is simply redundant - it will whine about missing dependencies.